# Strange "update twitter" notification

Tags: notifications

A few weeks ago, a new notification item appeared on my tray. It's worded in a way similar to normal update notifications, but it's not one of them, and it makes reference to software I haven't installed. See this image:

[image: Strange notification highlighted next to standard notifications]

The screen grab shows two standard update notifications: "X applications updated" and "X updates need approval". However, there's also a different one that reads "1 new update - Touch to download Twitter". Not only this one is different, the really strange thing is that I DON'T have Twitter installed, so there should be anything to update.

Aside: I use a Twitter client, but it's called Tweet Lanes and it normally upgrades through the normal routes. This doesn't seem related.

My tablet is a 2011 Samsung Galaxy 10.1, running Android 4.0.4. Maybe the notification is generated by the OEM software provided by Samsung?

Is there a way to tell which programs are showing which notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notification appears to be coming from apps installed from the [Firefox Marketplace](https://marketplace.firefox.com/) on Firefox for Android.

These apps can be found by opening the menu in Firefox and going to Tools > Apps.